# Flask application with SocketIO transport mode "polling" giving 400 Bad Request error

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, polling, flask-socketio

I have a flask application running locally and on my device's IP address.
In my `app.py` file, I have configured SocketIO with the below options.

```
import eventlet

socketio.init_app(app, async_handlers=True, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode='eventlet', allow_upgrades=False,transports=["polling"])
# rest of the code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

On client side, below is what I am trying to do.

```
let socket = io.connect("http://192.168.10.3:5000", {transports: ["polling"]})
socket.on("attendance", function(data) {
    let lastIndex = $("#attendees-table tr").length;
    // rest of the code
})
```

I am getting [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As0Ez.png) on console.
I have also checked the versions compatibility of flask-SocketIO and JavaScript socket and they are compatible. Flask-SocketIO version 5.3.2 (server) and socket.io version 4.5.4 (client)

Reason why I am using polling and not websocket is because websockects are not supported on shared hosting.
I have spent full day to solve it, I just can't figure out what I am missing :( Please help.

Comment: You need to look at the server logs to see what's going on. Please see the troubleshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO documentation to learn how to enable logging, then add these logs to your question.

Comment: @Miguel Grinberg I just modified this line of code `socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", allow_upgrades=False,transports=["polling"])` and removed `{transports: ["polling"]}` on client side and everything worked. Unfortunately, it turned out that Flask-SocketIO will entirely not work on shared hosting even with polling :(